# How To Convert Nutiteq lib's Coordinates into GPS Coordinates

Tags: dictionary, nutiteq

hello mates hope you having a nice day, its been a long time i am trying to convert back the coordinates that the nutiteq map creates from the location to the lat/long .

the coordinates are created using this method :

```
public MapPos fromWgs84(double lon, double lat)
 {
double x = lon * 111319.49079327358D;
double y = Math.log(Math.max(0.0D, Math.tan(lat * 0.008726646259971648D +  0.7853981633974483D))) * 6378137.0000000009D;
 return new MapPos(x, y);
 }

outPut =  some thing like this >>  x : 5734816.645344431  y : 4273005.026162199
```

is there any one who can help me how can i convert these coordinates back to lat/long , since i am not good at math methods and cant revert these :/ thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutiteq lib has class EPSG3857 and this has methods for both fromWgs84() and toWgs84:

```
Projection proj = new EPSG3857(); 
MapPos mercator = proj.fromWgs84(new MapPos(13.38933, 52.51704);

MapPos wgs = proj.toWgs84(mercator); // should return 13.38933, 52.51704
```

Comment: yeah but that was not extact same in longitude, any way thanks